# Does the category of stable infinity categories form a "subtractive Waldhausen" category?

Tags: higher-category-theory, kt.k-theory-and-homology, algebraic-k-theory, infinity-categories

In "The $K$-theory spectrum of varieties", Jonathan Campbell introduces the notion of a *subtractive Waldhausen category*, a slight generalization of the notion of Waldhausen category that includes in particular $\mathbf{Var}_{X}$ for a scheme $X$. This allows Campbell to define the Grothendieck spectrum of varieties $K(\mathbf{Var}_X)$ as the K-theory spectrum of the subtractive Waldhausen category $\mathbf{Var}_X$. Let me recall the definitions; see https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.03136.pdf for details.

**Definition:** A ***subtractive Waldhausen category*** is a category $\mathscr{C}$ together with subcategories $\mathbf{cof}(\mathscr{C})$ of "cofibrations", $\mathbf{fib}(\mathscr{C})$ of "fibrations", and $w(\mathscr{C})$ of "weak equivalences", together with a collection of "subtraction sequences" $\{a \to b \leftarrow c\}$ satisfying the following conditions:

1. $\mathscr{C}$ has a zero object $\varnothing$.
2. $\mathbf{cof}(\mathscr{C})$, $\mathbf{fib}(\mathscr{C})$, and $w(\mathscr{C})$ contain all isomorphisms
3. Pullbacks of cofibrations and fibrations exist and satisfy base change
4. $a \to a\sqcup b \leftarrow b$ is a subtraction sequence for all $a,b \in \mathscr{C}$
5. Every cofibration $a \to b$ extends uniquely to a subtraction sequence $a \to b \leftarrow c$; every fibration $e \leftarrow f$ extends uniquely to a subtraction sequence $d \to e \leftarrow f$.
6. Formation of these subtraction sequences is functorial for fiber squares of cofibrations
7. Subtraction sequences are stable under base change
8. Pushouts of cofibrations along cofibrations exist and are cofibrations; moreover, pushout squares among cofibrations are also pullback squares.
9. Pushout products of cofibrations are cofibrations.
10. Subtraction sequences interact well with pushouts along cofibrations (see the paper for the precise formulation).
11. Pushouts of cofibrations along cofibrations are stable under weak equivalences; formation of subtraction sequences is stable under weak equivalences.

**Notation:** Let $\mathsf{St}$ denote the $\infty$-category of (small) stable $\infty$-categories and exact functors. Let $\mathbf{cof}(\mathsf{St})$ be the wide subcategory of fully faithful left adjoint functors, $\mathbf{fib}(\mathsf{St})$ the wide subcategory of fully faithful *right* adjoint functors, and $w(\mathsf{st})$ the wide subcategory of equivalences. Let $\mathbf{sub}(\mathsf{St})$ be the collection of sequences $\mathscr{A} \xrightarrow{i} \mathscr{B} \xleftarrow{j} \mathscr{C}$ where the cofiber of $i$ is the left adjoint to $j$ (equivalently the cofiber of $j$ is the right adjoint to $i$).

**Question:** Do the data $(\mathsf{St}, \mathbf{cof}(\mathsf{St}), \mathbf{fib}(\mathsf{St}), w(\mathsf{St}), \mathbf{sub}(\mathsf{St}))$ form a subtractive Waldhausen category?

Comment: How is it compared with Clark Barwick's [On the algebraic K-theory of higher categories](https://arxiv.org/abs/1204.3607)?

Comment: @Z.M in St, pushouts of coreflective inclusions along arbitrary functors do not in general remain coreflective inclusions, so the notion of Waldhausen $\infty$-category cannot apply here.